# How to check if an array of string elements is found inside another array with jQuery.inArray()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a `<SELECT multiple="multiple">` box with options.

I store the selected options in a **JS** variable - `selectedFeatures`.

I want to pass `selectedFeatures` array variable of options to `jQuery.inArray()` - but the function is designed to take and check for one value only.

I can show/hide( or filter ) the markers on my map if I actually specify an index of an element like so: `selectedFeatures[0]` inside `inArray()`

..but since I may select multiple options from a select box this method of filtering doesn't work.

*How can I check if an array of items in found inside another array with* ***JS/jQuery***?

```
// store selected options as an array of string elements inside the variable
var selectedFeatures = $("#features").val();
// for every element inside 'markers.houses' array...                   
$(markers.houses).each(function(index, elem){
    // check if any of the values inside the 'selectedFeatures' array are found
    // also inside a sub-array 'features' inside every element of 'markers.houses'
    // array. if 'true' show that particular marker, otherwise hide the marker
    if(jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures, elem.features) !== -1 || jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures, elem.features) > -1){
        markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
    }else{
        markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

> **Fig 1.1** - *store selected options in an array variable and use it with* `jQuery.inArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for can be solved with PHP's `array_diff` function. I know you're not using PHP, but that's why there is [`array_diff` on PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_diff:309), a project dedicated to porting PHP functions into JavaScript.

Anyway, to solve this you basically want to call `array_diff(selectedFeatures,elem.features).length == 0`. (You may need to swap the arguments around, I'm not sure which array is which in your question)

`array_diff` returns the elements of the first array that are not present in the others. If all of the elements in the first array are also in the second array (ie. array1 is a subset of array2), then the returned array will be empty, hence its length is zero.

Comment: Hmm. But how will returning elements that aren't found in second array solve my problem? Assuming I get 3 out of 5 elements in the first array not found in the second array. So `array_diff` returns 3 elements, and how would I use that to solve my problem?

Comment: Since those three elements are not in the second array, that means the first array has extra stuff in it that shouldn't be there for your test to pass.

Comment: But the other two elements got matched, therefore I should show the markers that have matched at least one element. Let's say user selected 'Swimming Pool' and 'BBQ' from my features select box. So, the user wants to see all markers( houses ) that have a swimming pool and/or a bbq. Therefore if a marker doesn't have 'Swimming Pool' and 'BBQ' in their feature's array then hide it, but if a marker matches at least 'BBQ' - show it on the map. So what is the point of me getting the non-matched elements returned? I must be missing something really obvious...

Comment: Okay, so you want *at least one* rather than *all or nothing*. In that case, simply check to see if the returned length is different to the initial length. If so, then there was at least one match.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to use the array_diff - http://jsfiddle.net/7Cwbn/60/

But I keep getting `undefined` when I try to `console.log(array_diff(selectedFeatures, elem.features).length)`.

Comment: You'll need to change `retArr` to `[]` instead of `{}`, so that it will be an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Check this library: [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#intersection)

And you could use _.difference(array, *others).

Or you can create your own function to check if values from one array are in another array.